# Как получать уведомления в чат когда приложение закрыто?

Tags: firebase-database, firebase-android

Подскажите как реализовать? Создал приложение на Firebase с личным чатом на realtime database.
А вот как получать уведомления о новых сообщениях, когда приложение закрыто? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Никак, если выключен сервер.

Если приложение закрыто/выключено - программа не работает, чудес в мире не бывает. Когда говорят что нужно разместить приложение на сервере у какого-нибудь провайдера, то под этим понимается, что сервер -- это постоянно включенный компьютер (аптайм 99,99%) на котором постоянно работает ваша программа. Обычно для этих целей программы пишут в режиме "запускается как сервис ОС windows" (для серверов на базе windows) или в режиме демона (то же самое но под *nix-системы.

Если же выключен клиент, то в принципе ответ может быть тем же самым - никак, но есть детали.

Во-первых, то, что клиентское приложение кажется пользователю "выключенным" -- не факт, что оно реально не работает: может быть свернулось в трею или имеет фоновую службу, которая продолжает работать. Плюс можете почитать про push-уведомления, это технология которая часто идёт рука под руку с этой темой.

Во-вторых, уведомления можно получить после выхода клиента из оффлайна: как только запустится клиент, подключится к серверу -- то скачает все новые сообщения с сервера (при условии, что сервер работал и сохранил эти сообщения).

В целом же стратегий много. У вас если чат построен на базе общего сервера -- придумать проще.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за развернутый ответ. Воспользуюсь наверно пока просто дублирующей отправкой уведомлений по почте. Не буду заморачиваться.